# How to install a .cer certificate on linux to use citrix receiver

Tags: directory, certificates, citrix

I'm new to Linux and using Citrix Receiver to work from home, and can't launch it without a .cer file. I have downloaded the.cer file to my computer, it's saved on my desktop and have been attempting to install and run the file but keep running into different issues. I have been attempting to follow the instructions given on this website:https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-ca-certificates-in-ubuntu-server/

But the terminal notifies me that there is no such file or directory every time I enter my file name.

Does anyone know why this keeps happening/ what is the easiest solution? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I am linking to the certificates of Firefox with this command: `sudo ln -s /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/* /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/`

Comment: You might also try renaming it to .crt and putting it `opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/` - as per [this site](https://www.tuqix.org/wordpress/?p=222).